# How to change App Part title dynamically?

Tags: client, web-parts, sharepoint-2013

I have developed an App Part (Client Web Part) for SharePoint 2013. Now it has a static title, that was configured in Elements.xml. I want to use a different title for my App Part.
Is it possible to change the App Part title dynamically?